# Fetch date only in JSP

Tags: html

I have tried one program which displays the full date format in JSP.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.*" %>


<html>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center">
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing
="0" width="460" bgcolor="#EEFFCA">

<tr>
<td width="100%"><font size="6" color
="#008000">&nbsp;Date Example</font></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><b>&nbsp;Current Date 
and time is:&nbsp; <font color="#FF0000">


<%= new java.util.Date() %>
</font></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output I got is Sun Mar 13 12:08:41 IST 2011
I need only the date. How can i get it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(new Date());
    out.println(formattedDate);
%>
```

Comment: You need to import the DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat inside JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **DateFormat** to format the output.

Between the two lines:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.*" %>


<html>
.....
```

insert the format code:

```
<%
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
%>
```

and then, change the show result line :

```
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
```

to

```
<%= date %>
```

btw, i think you should study that the jsp file how to work with java.
sure, it just only my suggest.